# Acumatica Report Designer Concat variable shows incomplete field

Tags: acumatica, report-designer

Strange issue- In a Concat() formula within Acumatica Report Designer, I have a string series. It's only showing incomplete data from the field though.

Example, the Concat() formula is this:

```
Concat([ARInvoice.CustomerLocationID], '-M-' , [ARInvoice.RefNbr] )
```

(So, trying to concatenate the Location with '-M-', followed by the full Invoice Reference number.)

I'm expecting to see this value:  FACILITY02-M-AR006530

Instead, Report Designer returns this value:  FACILITY02-M-AR

I confirmed this isn't a field-size issue or a text alignment issue. It seems like Acumatica is just not returning the full value for Invoice Reference number.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same strange behavior, but I found a solution.
In your expression, wrap the expression with CStr

```
CStr(Concat([ARInvoice.CustomerLocationID], '-M-' , [ARInvoice.RefNbr]))
```